# Adding tags with Django-Taggit

Tags: django-taggit

I have tried different tutorials for Django-taggit, but for some reason they all show how to add tags through Admin. I was wondering can I add tags using View and template while creating an instance of Model? or should I add tags to existing items only? Is there any recent tutorials for Django-Taggit or my be better app for Tags?

Answer (score 4):

Their [documentation](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) is pretty swell. Once you have your model set up, you can use the tag field just like any other field in a form. It will automatically be set up to parse the tags.

Here is a very basic working example.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import NewspaperIndex
from .forms import NewIndexForm

def overview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewIndexForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = NewIndexForm()

    indexes = NewspaperIndex.objects.all()

    context = {'form': form,
               'indexes': indexes
           }

    return render(request, 'newsindex/overview.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class NewspaperIndex(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()
    abstract = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
import datetime

from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import NewspaperIndex


class NewIndexForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = NewspaperIndex
        fields = ['title', 'date', 'abstract', 'tags']
```

templates/newsindex/overview.html

```
  <form class="" action="./" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add a tag from a shell, try:

```
tag='tag to add'
post=NewspaperIndex.objects.all()[0] #pick an object, to add tag to
post.tags.add(tag)
```